# Tor doesn't launch on Arch with "XPCOMGlueLoad error"

Tags: linux

Tor doesn't launch on a fresh Arch install with "XPCOMGlueLoad error" despite following all instructions available.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: install `dbus-glib` from pacman. (`sudo pacman -Syu dbus-glib`)